# python altair line chart cut off by count

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I am currently trying to cut off a line chart in Altair. My code so far is:

```
    Chart(orient_frame).mark_line().encode(
    x = X('year:O'),
    y = Y('count(type:N)', scale=Scale(domain=(0,2500)),
    color = Color('type:N')
    )
```

the count(type:N) goes up to values over 9100 and I want to cut them out of the graph entirely. But Scale() does not cut of the line, so one line 'shoots out of the graph'.

I have also already tried

```
    Chart(orient_frame).mark_line().encode(
        x = X('year:O'),
        y = Y('count(type:N)'),
        color = Color('type:N')
    ).transform_data(
        filter='count(type:N) < 2500'
    )
```

but it just empties the output entirely. Can anyone help me here? It would be great! 
This is the output of the first so far

[image]

As for a minimal working example was asked:

```
import altair as al
import pandas as pd

#Create a simple 1 variable example
answers = ['No' for _ in range(3)]
answers.extend(['Yes' for _ in range(5)])
answers.extend(['Maybe' for _ in range(20)])

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'var1': answers})

#create Chart
al.Chart(dataframe).mark_bar().encode(
    x=al.X('var1:N'),
    y=al.Y('count(*):Q', scale=al.Scale(domain=(0,6)))

)
```

In this example I want to 'zoom in' to the yes/no answers because I do not care about the maybe-answers.

I can fix the scale, but i can't prevent the bar of maybe to go up the full 20-ticks.

Comment: Can you put a minimal working example, so that we can just use the DF to figure what's going wrong.

Comment: @NipunBatra Sure, i'll just add it to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, Altair doesn't hide any data. See: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/316#issuecomment-292560808

However, if you still wish to hide some data, you'd need to use the `clamp` argument.

```
import altair as al
import pandas as pd

#Create a simple 1 variable example
answers = ['No' for _ in range(3)]
answers.extend(['Yes' for _ in range(5)])
answers.extend(['Maybe' for _ in range(20)])

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'var1': answers})

#create Chart
al.Chart(dataframe).mark_bar().encode(
    x=al.X('var1:N'),
    y=al.Y('count(*):Q', scale=al.Scale(domain=(0, 6), clamp=True))

)
```

This produces the following output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried clamp=True before but did not add the :Q to the count(*):Q on the y-axis. It seems that this is mandatory for the clamp-option...

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that ^^